# In spring project works even if I give the oauth2 client-id parameter incorrectly

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

In my project I use keycloak for oauth2
What exactly do the following parameters mean? At what stage does it come into play? If I give the wrong client-id parameter, my project stands up and the Token is validated.

Note: If I enter an invalid token, security catches it, so there is no problem at the Security layer.

I get the token from keycloak with the following request.

```
username:test
password:test1
client_id:client-payment
grant_type:password
client_secret:azgf9E8QZxG6lKAYbsYT1
```

in my application.properties file

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=client-test
```

Even if I enter the parameter incorrectly, the token is validated. Exactly why and when are these parameters used?

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.provider=keycloak
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=client-test
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret=azgf9E8QZxG6lKAYbsYT1
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid,read,write
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8087/login/oauth2/code/keycloak


spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.authorization-uri=http://localhost:8087/realms/realm-payment/protocol/openid-connect/auth
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.token-uri=http://localhost:8087/realms/realm-/protocol/openid-connect/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8087/realms/realm-/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.jwk-set-uri=http://localhost:8087/realms/realm-/protocol/openid-connect/certs
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-info-authentication-method=header
```

**My Security Class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    private final AuthenticationEntryPoint tokenAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    private final CustomAuthenticationManagerResolver customAuthenticationManagerResolver;

    public SecurityConfig(
            @Qualifier("customAuthenticationEntryPoint") AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint,
            @Qualifier("tokenAuthenticationEntryPoint") AuthenticationEntryPoint tokenAuthenticationEntryPoint,
            CustomAuthenticationManagerResolver customAuthenticationManagerResolver) {
        this.authenticationEntryPoint = authenticationEntryPoint;
        this.tokenAuthenticationEntryPoint = tokenAuthenticationEntryPoint;
        this.customAuthenticationManagerResolver= customAuthenticationManagerResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .cors().and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer().authenticationEntryPoint(tokenAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                    .authenticationManagerResolver(request -> customAuthenticationManagerResolver.resolveAuthenticationManager());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Can you explain the situation?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining configuration for an `oauth2ResourceServer`, the client properties are just ignored. You might have `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` on your classpath as well as some `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver` properties defined somewhere. Resource server configuration don't care about client ID

##### Note

`grant_type:password` is deprecated and should not be used. Like **really not**. This comes with well known (and exploited) vulnerabilities. Use `authorization_code` instead.

Comment: But if I remove "spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=client-test" this property.
 it is giving the error "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client id must not be empty.
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientProperties.validateRegistration(OAuth2ClientProperties.java:68) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]".  
I don't understand exactly what you want to say. Can you elaborate a little more? Why does it work even if I enter the client-id parameter incorrectly?

Comment: I guess that the client configuration is evaluated (maybe because you have `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` on your classpath), but OAuth2 flows are never initiated because you don't have the Java conf for it. Client ID and secrets are used to get tokens (and during introspection on resource servers configured that way)